# How to get the maximum width and height coordinates of an iOS device display in Appium?

Tags: python, ios, instruments, appium, pytest

I am using the [appium python-client](https://github.com/appium/python-client) library to run a [[py.]test](http://pytest.org) on iOS and Android devices. I noticed that many iOS tests crashed with `tap point is not within the bounds of the screen`. Looking into the tests is seemed weird as the supplied coordinates were seemingly within the reported bounds of the device display.

The following snippet illustrates my problem:

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction

def test_max_screen_size(appium_driver):

    driver = appium_driver

    window_size = driver.get_window_size()
    max_width = window_size["width"] - 1
    max_height = window_size["height"] - 1 

    action = TouchAction(driver)
    action.tap(None, max_width, max_height).perform()
```

Here I am trying to tap the most *extreme* point of the display.

This test **passes** on **Android** devices and **fails** on **iOS** simulator devices(I haven't yet tested real iOS devices - but I am certain it will also crash).

Is this an **Appium bug** or am I doing something wrong?

My environment: 
`Appium 1.3.4`
`iOS 8.1`
[`current Appium Python client`](https://github.com/appium/python-client)
`Python 2.7.6`

## Update

I spend a bit more time on this issue.

First I ran this simple UIAutomation script via Instruments:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var max_width = target.rect().size.width;
var max_height = target.rect().size.height

UIALogger.logMessage("width: " + max_width + " height:" + max_height);

target.tap({x:max_width, y:max_height});
```

When you run this on an iPhone 4s you get `max_width = 320` and `max_height = 480` as it is a `2x` [retina display](http://www.iphoneresolution.com/) - exactly what Appium tells us and what is expected.

In case you increase either variable the script will fail as expected with: `Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: tap point is not within the bounds of the screen on line 8 of New Script`.

This means that **Appium** must be sending something that **Instruments** does not like.

So, the next point of failure could be the **appium python client**. I used [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to go to the very position where the clients talks to the appium server:

```
../remote_connection.py(349)execute()
-> return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
(Pdb) l
344             command_info = self._commands[command]
345             assert command_info is not None, 'Unrecognised command %s' % command
346             data = utils.dump_json(params)
347             path = string.Template(command_info[1]).substitute(params)
348             url = '%s%s' % (self._url, path)
349  ->         return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
350
351         def _request(self, method, url, body=None):
352             """
353             Send an HTTP request to the remote server.
354
(Pdb) url
u'http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/c9e49cb0-d291-4fb5-8aef-d89b9ceaa759/touch/perform'
(Pdb) data
'{"sessionId": "c9e49cb0-d291-4fb5-8aef-d89b9ceaa759", 
  "actions": [{"action": "tap", "options": {"y": 479, "x": 319, "count": 1}}]}'
```

This shows that also the **appium python client** seems to be doing what you would expect of it.

This leaves the **Appium** server as next **point of failure**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after digging for a while I finally found the answer. Unlike Instruments, where you can perform any tap relative to the full screen, Appium has chosen to limit you to the bounds of your application. This means if you have the **menu-bar** showing it will reduce your clickable area by the height of the menu-bar.

You can see this in the appium server log:

```
1  info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"width":320,"height":480}}
2  info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"width":320,"height":480},"sessionId":"b363bc3f-969b-4d7c-94e9-a504ffa08661"}
3  info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/b363bc3f-969b-4d7c-94e9-a504ffa08661/window/current/size 200 90.756 ms - 98 {"status":0,"value":{"width":320,"height":480},"sessionId":"b363bc3f-969b-4d7c-94e9-a504ffa08661"}
4  info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/b363bc3f-969b-4d7c-94e9-a504ffa08661/touch/perform {"sessionId":"b363bc3f-969b-4d7c-94e9-a504ffa08661","actions":[{"action":"tap","options":{"y":479,"x":319,"count":1}}]}
5  info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().rect()"
6  info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().rect()
7  info: [debug] [INST] 2015-01-29 00:27:53 +0000 Debug: Got new command 8 from instruments: UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().rect()
8  info: [debug] [INST] 2015-01-29 00:27:53 +0000 Debug: evaluating UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().rect()
9  info: [debug] [INST] 2015-01-29 00:27:53 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
10 info: [debug] [INST] 2015-01-29 00:27:53 +0000 Debug: responding with:
11 info: [debug] [INST] 2015-01-29 00:27:53 +0000 Debug: Running system command #9: /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.35_2/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"origin":{"x":0,"y":20},"size":{"width":320,"height":460}}}...
12 info: [debug] Socket data received (82 bytes)
13 info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
14 info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"origin":{"x":0,"y":20},"size":{"width":320,"height":460}}}
15 info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().tapWithOptions({\"tapOffset\":{\"x\":0.996875,\"y\":1.041304347826087},\"tapCount\":1,\"touchCount\":1})"
16 info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().tapWithOptions({"tapOffset":{"x":0.996875,"y":1.041304347826087},"tapCount":1,"touchCount":1})
```

In `line 2` you can see how the server responds with the *device resolution*.
In `line 14` you can see the application resolution: `320x460` and in the following line you see where my (now relative) click actually landed: `{"x":0.996875,"y":1.041304347826087}`.

This was unexpected and I hope the API description will point this out - That a tab in Appium is performed relative to the application-window (not the full display window).

## long story short

I now have to use `<driver>.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]').size` to replace `<driver>.get_window_size()` for iOS.